Android, the app gets stuck in an infinite loop when I try to open a link, that exist in the manifest file
I have scenerio where I deeplink url : www.business.co.uk/some_search?someparams=data
I have 2 cases,
I send this link to a backend service where the params is extracted and returned to my app to perform a search based on that result.
The second scenario is when the backend fails to sanitise this link,  I want to open the link in a webBrowser.
The Issue:
Because I have the path in my manifest, when my backend service returns the same link. I open that link in a browser.
I get into a scenario where the OS thinks my app can handle the URI and deeplinks it again, and i get stuck in an infinite loop.
I can change that path, and it looks like the manifest can only access the path and can't touch the query params,( i was hoping i could had a query params but this din't wor either).
does have a nice solution, I can prevent this infinite loop, to make it so when my app opens a browser it don't deeplink.
I tried adding a extra param to stop the deeplink, but the param can't be indentified an the manifest level, so this deeplink always happen no matter what.
I can't change my path and as you can see it is small path so not much can be done.

Does this answer your question? Android - Open url in external browser causes an infinite loop

Yes, this has fixed my issue. @dominicoder

Intent filter based on query param will be supported in Android 15
Android 15 Query param intent filter
For now you can use either a WebView or AndroidX browser library to open url you get from your server.
AndroidX browser library using this you can directly launch a chrome tab in app.
implementation ‘androidx.browser:browser:1.0.0’

Alternatively you can open in webview as below
 webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
 webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
 webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");

